# cloning a partition to a partition of different format

Tags: cloning

If I clone a partition (I can be using `dd` command or clonezilla software or anything) with `ext4` format to partition of `xfs` format:

1. will I have any issue/error?
2. The resultant data/partition will be `ext4` or `xfs` formatted ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you clone a partition of type `ext4`, the target partition will be completely overwritten with a direct and complete copy of the source partition. As such it will end up as being of type `ext4`. That's what cloning means.

On the other hand if you copy all the files from a filesystem of type `ext4` to a filesystem of type `xfs`, that's not a clone but you will have copied all the data and your underlying filesystem type will remain as you have configured it.

Comment: First format with xfs, then copy or rsync the data there.

Comment: @Baazigar your suggestion will not work for a clone

Comment: It will if the practical definition of clone is to get the entire file/directory structure intact from one partition to the other. I think if it is strictly a question for a strict clone, doesn't changing the file system break the definition of clone? in that case the question is not sane.

Comment: @Baazigar that possible ambiguity (and incorrectness) is why I answered the question with two possible alternatives. a _clone_ is more than just a _copy_. If you want to press the point you are welcome to offer your own Answer.